# what percentage of the world’s population is religious?

Tags: warfare, religion, population, gods

I recall asking a question that applies to Hell, but I have since realized that said story idea didn’t make a lot of sense.

I have been thinking and thinking and thinking, and I think I’ve finally thought of a story that applies to Hell, and actually makes sense.

Before I can ask my question, I’ll have to apply some context about my story.

Basically, God has deemed the human race as a failure and abandoned them, allowing the armies of the damned to conquer Earth, which becomes the tenth circle of Hell.

After the defeat of Earth’s forces, the human population is enslaved, and the demons, due to their hatred of anything similar to God, commit genocide on all people they consider to be religious, such as Christians, Jews, Muslims, Mormons, and Gnostics.

My question is, what percentage of the world’s population could be considered religious.

PS. This isn’t a reflection of my views towards religion. I simply came up with this idea because it makes sense for something like Hell to do. I’m sorry if my question offends anyone.

Comment: `I have brainstormed and brainstormed and brainstormed...` Nitpicking here, I know. "[Brainstorming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainstorming) is a **group** creativity technique...". So, just from curiosity, how many of you are collocated inside you? ;p

Comment: Just me. What’s a better word to describe a single person thinking?

Comment: Well... _thinking_? Maybe _thinking hard, again and again_

Comment: This is not a question of worldbuilding, it is about demographics. Also, this is a relatively well-known statistic; a simple Google search will get you the information you need. As a result, I am voting to close this.

Comment: Dying Buddhist: amitabha so it's official? Demon: I don't know but I care more about quota.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations

Comment: Also, are you asking for *any* religious people or specifically Christians? Maybe abrahamic religions - Christians, Jews, and Muslims? Or is it *any* religion? Do Shintoists and Buddhists also fall to the demon's wrath even if they don't believe in (an Abrahamic/singular) God? And so on and so forth. How strict are demons about enacting their revenge? Also, worth noting - when people are persecuted for their religious beliefs at least some would change said beliefs. People are (un-)surprisingly open to new ideas when their life depends on it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the zeroth circle of hell?

Comment: @StarfishPrime to be fair...it most likely wouldn't be a circle of Hell. Unless the demons just happen to be really big fans of Dante Alighieri. The "circles of Hell" is purely his invention and isn't in any way related to any teachings of what (Christian) Hell is like.

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers to this question. The easy answer is how many people self-identify as religious. [Pew Research report](https://www.pewforum.org/2012/12/18/global-religious-landscape-exec/)s that 84% of the world population identifies with some kind of religion, with major groups being Christians (32%), Muslims (23%) and Hindus (15%).

The second approach, which is much harder and controversial, is to ask how many people actually follow their faith correctly, and whether they are strong followers, weak followers, or followers in name only. Or to use the jargon, the hard approach is to try and measure the [religiosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religiosity) of the population. This is necessarily controversial and imperfect, because you have to decide what you measure. Unfortunately you can't directly measure, "this person really believes what they're saying."

For example, 76% of the USA is affiliated with some religion. However, if you ask people "did you attend a religious service last week" [then only about 40% of the population responds affirmatively.](https://news.gallup.com/poll/166613/four-report-attending-church-last-week.aspx) Now, some of that is because people were out of town or on vacation, or they were sick. It also includes people who are sincerely religious but are unable to attend their religious services regularly (such as the elderly who are not able to get out of the house). But a big chunk of the difference between the 76% that claim religious affiliation and the 40% of the people who are actually going to church is just a lack of sincere religious motivation.

You can come up with lots of religiosity measures like this: did you attend religious services, did you give money to a religion and how much, did you volunteer your time with a religious organization, did you read your selected holy book, etc. Which one accurately measures religious motivation? That's the controversial and opinion-based part, so I'll let you look those answers up yourself.

Comment: `is just a lack of sincere religious motivation.` Umm... are you conflating 'religious institutions + socialized rituals' and 'religious faith' as a single thing? So that if one side is missing, then the 'religiosity' is a fake? If so, how about the [hermits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermit#Notable_Christian_hermits), enough many of them being sanctified?

Comment: If you want to measure religiosity, but don't waste a single thought on acting the way your religion demands, but only superficial things like showing up for a ritual, then you really didn't give a good answer.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi No, as my answer already says, measuring religiosity is necessarily difficult and imperfect. We can't objectively and impartially measure "religious faith" in any meaningful way among the population, so the best we can do is pick a metric as a proxy for religious faith and measure that thing. Please take the time to read the sources as these are common questions and objections to measuring religiosity.

Comment: @Burki The starting assumption is that there are strong adherents of a faith and weak adherents of a faith, and our measure of religiosity is an attempt to try and understand the difference between those two groups. We cannot objectively measure things like "has sincere religious belief" and the only thing we can do is pick an objective measure and go with that. But, this is also not perfect because even the strongly religious do not have perfect orthodoxy and orthopraxy. Any measure we pick is fallible and the results are open to interpretation, but it's all we can do.

Comment: @Burki However, I'll also point out that all of the Abrahamic religions, which account for most of the world's faithful, have strong admonishments to be a part of religious community that meets regularly. Attending rituals is superficial according to you, but to someone else can be a sincere expression of faith. Hence the problem with and controversiality of defining measures of religiosity I discussed above.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I think its clear from the fact that Christianity is the biggest religion in the US, and Christianity heavily emphasizes social rituals.  If people aren't attending these rituals, they're probably not very religious.

Comment: @David yet you mention only the rituals. And while i'm not a religious person myself, i am pretty sure that while being important, living according to the teachings of a religion is considered even more important, by every religion i've heard of. And you completely fail to take that into account.

Comment: @Burki Apparently you failed to read the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: No, @David, i read it. There's still not a thing about "you shouldn't kill/steal/..." in it. It's still just superficial ceremony.

Answer (score 1):

### Everyone

You can argue that everyone is religious.

At some level you have to accept some set of postulates that simply cannot be proven to be true. Ergo, you have to Believe. Belief in a set of postulates makes that essentially a religion. Therefor you are by definition religious - like it or not.

### No One

A Religion is a set of requirements and values. Its impossible for anyone to actually embody those requirements 100%. Take your pick of reasons:

- Being 100% a religion makes you 0% human
- The religion has conflicting tenets. Adopting one means not adopting the other, therefor you are not actually practicing the religion (just the bits you like).
- No one is an actual believer. The reason why "god" threw away the project. If there is belief it is in the dogmatic structure of the religion itself, instead of the infinite and transcendent idea behind it.

... and why kill millions of fresh slaves? Let them sweat for you first, then kill and torment them later. *These things after all have to be relished.*

### You Choose

This is your story, are you telling it from where:

- humanity was obliterated - hanging on by the last fingernail in some sort of apocalyptic world, or guerilla survival/warfare?
- humanity is so corrupt that hunting down the last "innocents" and "worshipers" is like some kind Spanish Inquisition - comfy chair and all?
- humanity survives in bulk and is faced daily by highly moralistic choices imposed on them by their new overlords? Not unalike a battle royal, every man for themselves (or in groups) vs the demons, and those other men over there who are throwing you to the demons.
- humanity is being forced into becoming demons by any means necessary. Those who were faithful being given specialised attention to ensure a *pleasant* experience for the demons - blind faith is so useful with appropriate guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, God has deemed the human race as a failure and abandoned them, allowing the armies of the damned to conquer Earth, which becomes the tenth circle of Hell.

[Hinduist version of Hell is temporary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka_(Hinduism)) and Hindu's don't have a single God (who can abandon the human race).

[The Buddhist Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naraka_(Buddhism)) is not a place of divine judgement or punishment.

[The Taoist hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diyu#Conceptions) is more like a purgatory.

> After the defeat of Earth’s forces, the human population is enslaved, and the demons, due to their hatred of anything similar to God, commit genocide on all people they consider to be religious, such as Christians, Jews, Muslims, Mormons, and Gnostics.

Whew! At least one third of human (religious?) population is safe then.

> My question is, what percentage of the world’s population could be considered religious.
>
> PS. This isn’t a reflection of my views towards religion. I simply came up with this idea because it makes sense for something like Hell to do. I’m sorry if my question offends anyone.

About that third of the human (more or less religious) population thinks that the punishment of their sins in the past life (or lives) happen still on Earth, just at the time of their next lives. And this with *active* participation of a judging god - who isn't actually involving in some sort of a strike a dereliction of duty. That God just judge the merits of the (past) individual in the face of the Karmic law, law obeyed even by their other Gods.

I must admit the Karmic Justice is one step above the concept of justice in Abrahamic religions.